# Discrete event simulation framework for discrete times in Julia

Tags: julia, simulation

I would like to receive constructive feedback on my simulation framework (this is for my thesis work). I have no formal background in programming, and I am wondering if there is a more effective and efficient way to structure my codes for better readability and scalabiilty so that people can easily understand, modify, and build on my codes while achieving high computational efficiency.

Here is a brief description of my simulation model. For each agent I create in my simulation world, they go through a number of event processes annually until they die, reach the maximum age (e.g., 111), or reach the max. time window (e.g., 2050 if an agent is created in 2015 and I set the time window to be 35). I am using a **modular** apporach, in which each module contains at least one process (so far I have not encoutered more than 1, but I think I would in the future): a process function for that module and input parameters for that process function.

To facilliate that framework, I have created an abstract type Simulation_Module under which event modules (birth and death) are contained.

**abstractModule.jl**:

```
abstract type Agent_Module end

abstract type Simulation_Module end

# sub modules
abstract type Birth_Module <: Simulation_Module  end
abstract type Death_Module <: Simulation_Module  end
```

**agent.jl**: Here is an agent module

```
mutable struct Agent{Z<:Bool,Y<:Int64}  <: Agent_Module
    sex::Z
    age::Y
    birth_year::Y
    cal_year::Y
    alive::Z
end

function set_agent!(ag, sex, age, birth_year,cal_year,alive)
    ag.sex = sex;
    ag.age= age;
    ag.birth_year = birth_year;
    ag.cal_year = cal_year;
    ag.alive = alive;
    nothing
end

agent = Agent(false,0,2015,2015,true)
```

**birth.jl**: Birth module

```
mutable struct Birth <: Birth_Module
    parameters::Union{AbstractDict,Nothing}
    process::Function
end

parameter_names = nothing

function birth_process(cal_year_index::Int64,parameters::Union{AbstractDict,Nothing}=nothing)::Bool
    rand(Bernoulli(0.5))
end

birth = Birth(Dict_initializer(parameter_names),birth_process)
```

**death.jl**

```
mutable struct Death <: Death_Module
    parameters::Union{AbstractDict,Nothing}
    process::Function
end

parameter_names = nothing

function death_process(ag::Agent,parameters::Union{AbstractDict,Nothing}=nothing)::Bool
    rand(Bernoulli(0.5))
end

death = Death(Dict_initializer(parameter_names),death_process)
```

**Simulation.jl**: It contains a struct for Simulation and a run function for running a simulation.

```
using Setfield, Distributions, StatsFuns
using TimerOutputs

function Dict_initializer(parameter_names::Union{Nothing,Vector{Symbol}})
    isnothing(parameter_names) ? nothing : Dict(parameter_names .=> missing)
end

# abstract types
include("abstractModule.jl")
# agent
include("agent.jl")
# event proceses
include("birth.jl")
include("death.jl")


mutable struct Simulation <: Simulation_Module
    max_age::Int64
    starting_calendar_year::Int64
    time_horizon::Int64
    n::Int64 # number of agents to create in each year
    Agent::Agent_Module
    Birth::Birth_Module
    Death::Death_Module
    OutcomeMatrix::AbstractDict # needs to be a dictionary
end


function run(simulation::Simulation_Module)

    # Is it better to define the fields of the simulation object
    # separately if I am going to use
    # them in simulation multiple times?
    max_age::Int64 = simulation.max_age
    min_cal_year::Int64 = simulation.starting_calendar_year
    max_cal_year::Int64 = min_cal_year + simulation.time_horizon - 1
    simulation.n = (isnothing(simulation.n) ? 100 : simulation.n)
    n::Int64 = simulation.n

    max_time_horizon::Int64 = simulation.time_horizon
    cal_years::Vector{Int64} = collect(min_cal_year:1:max_cal_year)

    # store events
    # total num of agents
    n_list = zeros(Int64,simulation.time_horizon,2)
    # store events by cal year, age, and sex for each event type
    event_list::Vector{String} = ["death","alive"]
    event_matrix = zeros(Int64,length(cal_years),max_age,2,length(event_list))

    # time the performance
    to = TimerOutput()

    # initiate variables
    tmp_n::Int64 = 0
    tmp_cal_year_index::Int64 = 0

    @timeit to "sleep" sleep(0.02)
    for cal_year in cal_years
        # for each calendar year
        @timeit to "calendar year $cal_year" begin
            tmp_cal_year_index = cal_year - min_cal_year + 1

            for i in 1:n
                # initialization: create a new agent
                set_agent!(simulation.Agent,simulation.Birth.process(tmp_cal_year_index),0,tmp_cal_year_index,tmp_cal_year_index,true)

                # update the total number of agents added to the simulation
                n_list[tmp_cal_year_index,simulation.Agent.sex+1] +=1

                # go through event processes for each agent until
                # death or max age or max time horizon
                while(simulation.Agent.alive && simulation.Agent.age <= max_age && simulation.Agent.cal_year <= max_time_horizon)

                    # I have other event processes

                    # death - the last process
                    if simulation.Death.process(simulation.Agent)
                        # dead
                        simulation.Agent.alive = false
                        event_matrix[simulation.Agent.cal_year,simulation.Agent.age+1,simulation.Agent.sex+1,1] += 1
                    else
                        # still alive!
                        event_matrix[simulation.Agent.cal_year,simulation.Agent.age+1,simulation.Agent.sex+1,2] += 1
                        simulation.Agent.age += 1
                        simulation.Agent.cal_year += 1
                    end

                end # end while loop

            end # end for loop: agents

        end # end of begin timeit

    end # end for loop: cal year
    print_timer(to::TimerOutput)

    # convert the event matrix into a dictionary
    tmp_event_dict = Dict()
    for jj in 1:length(event_list)
        tmp_event_dict[event_list[jj]] = [event_matrix[:,:,1,jj],event_matrix[:,:,2,jj]]
    end

    # reshape event matrix into a dictionry of list of matrices
    simulation.OutcomeMatrix = Dict("n" => n_list,
                                    "outcome_matrix" => tmp_event_dict)

    print("\n Simulation finished. Check your simulation object for results.")
    return nothing
end

# test run
simulation = Simulation(111,2015,25,5000, agent, birth, death,Dict());

run(simulation)
```

You can directly download the files from:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nrip5dc2rus6oto/AADIlZsngwjuUOwir9O2AeMsa?dl=0

I have just provided two modules, and my run function is very simple but you can imagine I would have many more processes and hence a complicated run function.

Besides any feedback you may have, I would like to know whether there is a better (in terms of readability, scalability, and efficiency) frameworks/tools I could use (e.g., software-wise, structure of "modules", julia types, built-in functions, etc).

If anything is unclear please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be useful to understand what is your objective, i.e. what you want to discover with your simulation. If you state more in details yr subject you may receive more domain specific suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was hoping to get feedback on my simulation framework, which is for a discrete event simulation for discrete time, and efficiency/effectivness.

Answer (score 1):

That was a fun one.  I only comment on the Julia parts, not the content, since the former was intense enough.

### Deconstruction

```
abstract type Simulation_Module end
```

In Julia, PascalCase, as in `SimulationModule`, is preferred for types.  For variable/function names, opinions differ between `flatcase` and  `snake_case`.

---

```
mutable struct Agent{Z<:Bool,Y<:Int64}  <: Agent_Module
    sex::Z
    age::Y
    birth_year::Y
    cal_year::Y
    alive::Z
end
```

Those type parameters make no sense at all.  `Bool` and `Int64` are concrete types, so just use them directly: `sex::Bool` etc.  I'd spell out `calendar_year` explicitely.  Replace `Int64` by `Int` unless you have specific reasons for using a certain size (`Int` is a uses the platforms word size).

Also, do think twice whether your types need to be mutable.  Perhaps the algorithm works just as well with immutable types and the respective style.

---

```
function set_agent!(ag, sex, age, birth_year,cal_year,alive)
    ag.sex = sex;
    ag.age= age;
    ag.birth_year = birth_year;
    ag.cal_year = cal_year;
    ag.alive = alive;
    nothing
end
```

That's a weird one, but I understand it follows from making `Agent` mutable.  I suggest to replace usages of `set_agent!` by updates with a new agent: `simulation.agent = Agent(...)`.

If you insist on this function: take care of proper spacing (`ag.age = age`), and return the updated instance from it (`return ag`).  Throw away those colons `;`, too.

BTW, you load `Setfield` below.  This function would be the ideal place to refactor using it.

---

```
mutable struct Birth <: Birth_Module
    parameters::Union{AbstractDict,Nothing}
    process::Function
end
```

Here we have the opposite case from `Agent`: `AbstractDict` and `Function` *are* abstract types, so you *do* want to make them parameters.  Besides, abstracting the dict type might be an overkill; isn't there more specific information you have?

Furthermore, is it really needed to distinguish between `nothing` and an empty dictionary?  Also, my point about mutability from above.

Suggestion:

```
mutable struct Birth{F, P} <: BirthModule
    parameters::Dict{Symbol, P}
    process::F
end
```

---

```
parameter_names = nothing
```

Uh.  You know what you are doing there?  You declare a *mutable global variable*, which is bad for type stability to begin with.  And then you write to it multiple times from the top level, in every `include`!

Make the variable local wherever you use it.

---

```
birth = Birth(Dict_initializer(parameter_names),birth_process)
```

Same here.  Make it local.

---

```
function Dict_initializer(parameter_names::Union{Nothing,Vector{Symbol}})
    isnothing(parameter_names) ? nothing : Dict(parameter_names .=> missing)
end
```

Style-wise, call it `init_parameters` or something.

And I suggest to get rid of it completely.  It's ugly and will lead to weird types.  Probably you want to avoid checking for the parameters being present in the simulation functions; you could refactor that by using convenience functions such as [`get!`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.get!-Tuple%7BFunction,Any,Any%7D) wherever the parameters are modified.

Or even better, implement immutable parameter updates using [`NamedTuple`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Core.NamedTuple) and `SetField`, with an appropriate initialization.

---

```
    Agent::Agent_Module
    Birth::Birth_Module
    Death::Death_Module
```

Fields should be in lower case.

In the case of `Simulation`, a mutable type seem reasonable to me.  But perhaps a more elegant design is possible by separating simulation parameters (agent, time horizon, max age) that stays constant from a mutable "simulation state" type.

---

```
OutcomeMatrix::AbstractDict # needs to be a dictionary
```

And why is it called a matrix, then?  Also, either make the dictionary type a parameter (`{D<:AbstractDict}`), or switch to a concrete type.

---

```
max_age::Int64 = simulation.max_age
```

The type assertion is not necessary.  Also, you have `SetField` to do this for you!

---

```
simulation.n = (isnothing(simulation.n) ? 100 : simulation.n)
```

`simulation.n` is an `Int64`, and thus cannot be `nothing`.

Pass the initial `n` as a parameter to the `run` function, or put it into the simulation parameter type I proposed before, or at least make the number a global `const`.

---

```
max_time_horizon::Int64 = simulation.time_horizon
```

Use consistent naming here.

---

```
cal_years::Vector{Int64} = collect(min_cal_year:1:max_cal_year)
```

`collect(min_cal_year:max_cal_year)` should suffice.  But think about whether you need to allocate this vector in the first place.  Aren't you only iterating over it?  Then the range is enough.  Or could you even just recalculate it in every step from the initial year and the current `n`?

---

```
n_list = zeros(Int64,simulation.time_horizon,2)
```

Not a good name.  It's neither a list (but a `Vector`), nor has it an appearent connection to `n`.

Also, it has fixed size.  You could replace it by a tuple or two variables.

Watch your spaces!

---

```
event_list::Vector{String} = ["death","alive"]
```

Symbols would be preferred: `[:death, :alive]`.

---

```
    tmp_n::Int64 = 0
    tmp_cal_year_index::Int64 = 0
```

Better names for that, please!  Or get rid of the variable all together.

---

```
event_matrix = zeros(Int64,length(cal_years),max_age,2,length(event_list))
```

Maybe this can get a better name, too... `events`?  And it seems that you didn't completely decide whether to make the kinds of events fixed or parametrizable.  If there are only ever going to be two kinds, use a `const N_EVENTS = 2`.  Otherwise, parametrize the simulation by event types (and then change how you handle `event_list`).

Also, that `2` needs to be a constant too, I have no idea what it the dimension stands for.  Perhaps use a type like [`AxisArray`](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/AxisArrays.jl) to make all dimensions more explicit.

Spacing, again!

---

```
n_list[tmp_cal_year_index,simulation.Agent.sex+1] +=1
```

Ah, so this should have been called `agent_counts` or like that.  Again, spacing!

```
n_list[tmp_cal_year_index, simulation.agent.sex + 1] += 1
```

And wait, what?  The `sex` is a `Bool`.  Why are you incrementing it?  Make the semantics of using a `Bool` to select the column more explicit.  Perhaps there is an array type that can do that.  You could create your own even (or give up the social construction of there being a limited number of two distinct sexes :))

---

```
if simulation.Death.process(simulation.Agent)
```

This looks like an updating operation.  In that case, the name of the field of the death module should be `process!`.

This also shows that you should add more docstrings.  Document the interface that `process!` needs to fulfill somewhere, too!

---

```
# convert the event matrix into a dictionary
    tmp_event_dict = Dict()
    for jj in 1:length(event_list)
        tmp_event_dict[event_list[jj]] = [event_matrix[:,:,1,jj],event_matrix[:,:,2,jj]]
    end

    # reshape event matrix into a dictionry of list of matrices
    simulation.OutcomeMatrix = Dict("n" => n_list,
                                    "outcome_matrix" => tmp_event_dict)
```

This looks a bit gross.  Suggestion: have a separate type for simulation results.  Then drop `OutcomeMatrix` and instead of writing the simulation result to the simulation object, return a simulation result object.

Apart from that:

- `tmp_` is a really bad prefix.  Try to construct the thing directly:

  ```
  outcome_matrix = [(event_matrix[:,:,1,jj], event_matrix[:,:,2,jj]) for jj in eachindex(event_list)]
  ```

  This also uses tuples instead of constant-length arrays, and avoids an untyped `Dict()`.

  Additionally, you copy over the whole event matrix into slices.  That's bad for memory.  You could use [views](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Views-(SubArrays-and-other-view-types)), or make the logic part of the suggested result type -- pack the event matrix into it, and add some nice custom accessors instead of the dictionary conversion.
- Once more, `OutcomeMatrix` is obviously not a matrix.  If you do something like this at all, use `Symbols` in the dict.  Even better, use a `NamedTuple` instead: `(;n = n_list, outcome_matrix = outcome_matrix)`, or in newer Julias  `(;n = n_list, outcome_matrix)` with the naming inferred automatically.

---

```
simulation = Simulation(111,2015,25,5000, agent, birth, death,Dict());
```

Again, this looks like Fortran with more indirection: you pass in a mutable object to use as the output.  Make the simulation result the return value of `run`.

Remove the colon.

### More general design suggestions

1. Think about whether you need so much abstraction.  E.g., the abstract base types for everything.
2. Perhaps try to rewrite `run` as a combination of an `init!` and a `step!` function on a mutable `SimulationState` object.  Then, derive an iterator from it so that you can do `for step in run(simulation) ...`.

Comment: Yeah, I was bored.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will go over these carefully and may bother you.